# how to show next card behind the current card on pageView on main screen with scrolling?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

**I want to like this,** https://dribbble.com/shots/3593825-Android-Card-Slider-Preview-Open-Source

how to show the next card behind the current card on the main screen with scrolling? I tried to create this. but I failed. this is my code. I don't know how to show the next card on the main screen?

```
PageView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
```

**make reverse order**

```
        reverse: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
```

**current card**

```
          if (position == currentPageValue.floor()) {
            return Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.identity()
                ..rotateY(currentPageValue - position),
              child: Container(
                color: position % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.pink,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "current card",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
```

**next card**

```
 else if (position == currentPageValue.floor() + 1) {
                return Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.identity()
                    ..rotateY(currentPageValue - position),
                  child: Container(
                    color: position % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.pink,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "next Card",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
              else {
                return Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  color: position % 2 == 0 ? Colors.yellow : Colors.black,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Page else",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            itemCount: 10,
          ),
```

the output is looks like this,

[image]

I need this,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`PageController controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);`

It is not exactly what you want, but setting `viewportFraction` property to the `PageController` may give you a clue.

Comment: I tried but change card size only. I dont know how to show next card behind the current card. I check with reducing `viewportFraction`.

Comment: is it possible to scroll?